# How to count words in a variable

Tags: macros, listofitems

I've defined a command to print dialogues for a musical characters, a very stripped down version is

```
\newcommand{\dialog}[2]{#1: #2}
\def \person1{\dialog{Marco}}
```

I can count how many times Marco had a line by creating a counter and placing it inside Marco's Def. However how could I count how many word were inside every #2 variable?

Comment: I'm sure we can help, but you need to clean up your request a bit.  First, the digit `1` cannot appear as part of a macro name defined with `\def\<macroname>`.  More importantly, you show `\dialog` with 2 inputs, but your usage with `Marco` only provides a single input.  So *what* is it you want searched for how many occurrences of *what*?

Comment: What algorithm do you wish to use for counting words? What about things like `\dialog{Marco}{Bla \textbf{important bla bla} not so important blabla!}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counting words is easy with the `listofitems` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\dialog[2]{#1: #2%
  \setsepchar{ }%
  \ignoreemptyitems%
  \readlist\myarg{#2}%
  \ (\myarglen{} word\ifnum\myarglen>1s\fi)%
}
\begin{document}
\dialog{Marco}{This}

\dialog{Marco}{This is}

\dialog{Marco}{This is a}

\dialog{Marco}{This is a test}
\end{document}
```

[image]